# How to get around this memoryview error in numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In this code snippet `train_dataset`, `test_dataset` and `valid_dataset` are of the type `numpy.ndarray`.

```
def check_overlaps(images1, images2):
    images1.flags.writeable=False
    images2.flags.writeable=False
    print(type(images1))
    print(type(images2))
    start = time.clock()
    hash1 = set([hash(image1.data) for image1 in images1])
    hash2 = set([hash(image2.data) for image2 in images2])
    all_overlaps = set.intersection(hash1, hash2)
    return all_overlaps, time.clock()-start

r, execTime = check_overlaps(train_dataset, test_dataset)    
print("# overlaps between training and test sets:", len(r), "execution time:", execTime)
r, execTime = check_overlaps(train_dataset, valid_dataset)   
print("# overlaps between training and validation sets:", len(r), "execution time:", execTime) 
r, execTime = check_overlaps(valid_dataset, test_dataset) 
print("# overlaps between validation and test sets:", len(r), "execution time:", execTime)
```

But this gives the following error:
(formatting as code to make it readable!)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-337e73a1cb14> in <module>()
     12     return all_overlaps, time.clock()-start
     13 
---> 14 r, execTime = check_overlaps(train_dataset, test_dataset)
     15 print("# overlaps between training and test sets:", len(r), "execution time:", execTime)
     16 r, execTime = check_overlaps(train_dataset, valid_dataset)

<ipython-input-14-337e73a1cb14> in check_overlaps(images1, images2)
      7     print(type(images2))
      8     start = time.clock()
----> 9     hash1 = set([hash(image1.data) for image1 in images1])
     10     hash2 = set([hash(image2.data) for image2 in images2])
     11     all_overlaps = set.intersection(hash1, hash2)

<ipython-input-14-337e73a1cb14> in <listcomp>(.0)
      7     print(type(images2))
      8     start = time.clock()
----> 9     hash1 = set([hash(image1.data) for image1 in images1])
     10     hash2 = set([hash(image2.data) for image2 in images2])
     11     all_overlaps = set.intersection(hash1, hash2)

ValueError: memoryview: hashing is restricted to formats 'B', 'b' or 'c'
```

Now the problem is I don't even know what the error means let alone think about correcting it. Any help please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that your method to hash arrays only works for `python2`. Therefore, your code fails as soon as you try to compute `hash(image1.data)`. The error message tells you that only `memoryview`s of formats unsigned bytes (`'B'`), bytes (`'b'`) of single bytes (`'c'`) are supported and I have not found a way to get such a view out of a `np.ndarray` without copying. The only way I came up with includes copying the array, which might not be feasible in your application depending on your amount of data. That being said, you can try to change your function to:

```
def check_overlaps(images1, images2):
    start = time.clock()
    hash1 = set([hash(image1.tobytes()) for image1 in images1])
    hash2 = set([hash(image2.tobytes()) for image2 in images2])
    all_overlaps = set.intersection(hash1, hash2)
    return all_overlaps, time.clock()-start
```

Comment: Yes you're right I am working on python3+. I used the function `bytes()` as: 
`hash(bytes(image1)))` and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help. 
And it is from the a large dataset of about 200000 MNIST images.

Comment: @user6692576 Glad I could help. `bytes()` actually gives you exactly the same result as `np.tobytes()` and also makes a copy of the data. I suspect it even calls the function internally. So for your purpose you can probably use them interchangeably.

Comment: Also `arr.tostring() == arr.tobytes() == bytes(arr)`.

Comment: From my simple benchmark, `hash(bytes(xxx)))` seems to be much slower (about 4 times) than `hash(xxx.tobytes())`, so using `xxx.tobytes()` is probably a better idea.